# Problem putting answers in a macro

Tags: macros, verbatim, answers

I want to put the `\begin{sol}` and `\end{sol}` from the answers package in a macro like

```
\newcommand{\assignment}[2]
{
\item #1
\begin{sol} #2 \end{sol}
}

###

\assignment{question}{answer}
```

It's just that answers use a verbatim environment that makes it miss the `\end{sol}` if it isn't written in the 'main' function.
Is there any way to use the `\expandafter`,`\csname` or such commands to let it just print the `\begin{sol} #2 \end{sol}` and then expand it after it has been printed in the main document?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they are [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it). You can also use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/863/how-do-i-mark-inline-code) as I did in my edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try

```
\newcommand{\assignment}[2]{\item #1\scantokens{\begin{sol}#2\end{sol}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use verbatim in macro arguments. I would make assignment an environment with one argument for the item instead. Alternatively you can use the following trick to place `\end{sol}` automatically after the `}` behind the answer:

```
\newcommand{\assignment}[1]{%
   \item #1
   \begin{sol}
    \def\endassignment{\end{sol}}%
    \bgroup
    \aftergroup\endassignment
    \let\dummy=%
}



\assignment{question}{answer}
```

Here the `{` in front of the `answer` is removed, so the `}` will match the internal `\bgroup`. Then `\aftergroup` is used to insert the `\end{sol}` afterwards.

(Using `\sol` and `\endsol` instead would be simpler, but I don't know if this environment relies on the extra group. Having to add it manually wouldn't make the code shorter.)